# Ubuntu 22.04 dock with extra space between the left edge of the screen and icons

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-dock

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04.

The application icons on the dock are left-padded from the left edge of the screen.

This setting does not let me open an application by clicking it by passing easily the mouse through the left edge of the screen, as I done in the previous Ubuntu versions.

How to remove that extra space?

I already searched inside dconf-editor.

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any hardware settings on the monitor that might effect this? That is what was the issue on mine.

Comment: @David all visible pixels on the monitor are clickable. Also the top-left-most one that highlight the `x` button to close the window (I put it at the top most). So it not depends on hardware

Comment: I can also reproduce this. This should probably be filed as an issue with the developers it it hasn't already.